# Every invertible matrix can be written as a finite composition of elementary matrices with real eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, matrix-decomposition

Suppose $\Psi$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix that does not have only real eigenvalues. I read that such a matrix can be written as a finite composition of elementary matrices with real eigenvalues. Specifically:

> Every automorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a finite composition of
>   automorphisms with real eigenvalues  (elementary  matrices).

I have not been able to find a proof of this, does anyone know how to show it?

Comment: The title claim is already wrong for $n=1$. Take the $1\times 1$-matrix $A=(i)$ with $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This statement is used in Step 6. on page 70 of these notes: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf - are these notes (which have now been released as a book) wrong?

Comment: Dear csss, the statement with automorphisms is correct, but the statement in your title is not correct, as you see already for the case $n=1$.

Comment: But invertible matrices correspond directly to automorphism, do they not? - https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Invertible_Matrix_corresponds_to_Automorphism - how can the statement be correct for automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but not for invertible $n\times n$ matrices if these are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard result from introductory linear algebra that, by multiplying by elementary matrices, you can *row reduce* any matrix into row reduced echelon form.

In the case of an invertible matrix, the row reduced echelon form is the identity matrix, which is also an elementary matrix, and so you get the theorem.

Comment: I don't understand. Say we have an invertible matrix $M$. How can the fact that $M$ has the identity as a row-reduced echelon form be used to show that $M$ is a finite composition of matrices with real eigenvalues?